# reading username and password values config values instead of hard coding in class

Tags: vb.net, encryption, connection-string, config

I am having a config file

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="UserName" value="encryptedusername"/>
    <add key="Password" value="encryptedpassword"/>  
</appSettings>
```

I want to decrypt them and acess them in my method. Presently it is hardcoded. I want to get the values from config and remove hardcoding in code. How do I change the method:

```
Private Function GetConnectionStringFromWebConfig() As String
    Dim strConnection As String
    'Dim intEnviroCount As Integer = 
    'ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("EnvironmentCount")
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strServer As String
    Dim strCatalog As String
    Dim strUserName As String
    Dim strPassword As String

    strServer = _SqlServer
    strCatalog = _Catalog
    strUserName = _UserName
    strPassword = _Password

    ' Add in required fields
    strConnection = "Data Source=" & strServer & "; Initial Catalog=" & strCatalog & "; Max Pool Size=500;"

    ' Add in (optional) user field
    If strUserName = "" Then
      strConnection &= "User ID=hardcodedusername;"
    Else
      strConnection &= "User ID=" & strUserName & ";"
    End If

    ' Add in (optional) password field
    If strPassword = "" Then
      strConnection &= "Password=Hardcodedpassword;"
    Else
      strConnection &= "Password=" & strPassword & ";"
    End If

    _strServer = strServer
    _strCatalog = strCatalog

    Return strConnection
End Function
```

I am trying to use

```
Dim UserPane As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"].ToString();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
namevaluecollection can not be converted to string
```

Comment: Looking at what you pasted in, it appears that you have some code that you inadvertently left uncommented: ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("EnvironmentCount")

Comment: That is commented our in code due to space it looks like that.. i edited it.